# Recursividad react y renderizado

Tags: reactjs, recursión, react-hooks

tengo el siguiente problema. Yo necesito traer un listado de empleados llamando una API; dichos empleados pueden tener subempleados y esos subempleados pueden tener otros subempleados hasta "n" numero de veces.

Debo listar en el frontend todos los empleados que estén por debajo de otro empleado por lo cual debo hacer llamadas recursivas para obtener los subempleados de mis empleados y asi sucesivamente

Mi problema es que a react no le da tiempo de obtener el listado y se renderiza antes de que obtenga todos los resultados

Los empleados los muestro en un "select" para que el usuario pueda seleccionar uno de ellos pero no los muestra en el primer render
¿Alguna sugerencia de como podría solucionarlo?

Esta es mi funcion recursiva

```
 const getEmpleadosRecursivo = async (idEmpleadoJefe: number, idProyecto: number) => {
        const empleadosRespuesta = await getEmpleadosACargoByProyecto(idEmpleadoJefe, idProyecto);
        empleadosRespuesta.forEach(async emp => {
            if (emp.idEmpleado !== idEmpleadoJefe) {
                const subEmpleados = await getEmpleadosACargoByProyecto(emp.idEmpleado, idProyecto);
                subEmpleados.forEach(async subEmpleado => {
                    if (subEmpleado.idEmpleado !== emp.idEmpleado) {
                        const obtenidos = await getEmpleadosRecursivo(subEmpleado.idEmpleado, idProyecto)
                        obtenidos.forEach(ob => {
                            empleadosRespuesta.push(ob)
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        return empleadosRespuesta
    }
```

Aqui mando a llamar la funcion cuando se inicializa el componente con el useEfect

```
    const respuesta = await getEmpleadosRecursivo(user.idUsuario, formData.idProyecto || 0);
    setEmpleados(respuesta);
```

Aqui muestro el listado que obtengo

```
                <TextField
                    select
                    onChange={(e) => { setFormDAta({ ...formData, idResponsable: Number(e.target.value) }) }}
                    value={formData.idResponsable}
                    margin="dense"
                    variant="outlined"
                    style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                    label="Reponsable"
                    fullWidth
                >
                    <MenuItem value="0">Selecciona un responsable</MenuItem>
                    {empleados.map(empleado => (
                        <MenuItem value={empleado.idEmpleado} key={empleado.idEmpleado}>{empleado.nombre}</MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </TextField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias controlar con un useState que no se renderize hasta que no haya acabado:

```
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
```

En el useEffect donde haces la llamada a la API:

```
const respuesta = await getEmpleadosRecursivo(user.idUsuario, formData.idProyecto || 0);
setEmpleados(respuesta);
setLoading(false);
```

Y el componente:

```
{!loading &&
                    <TextField
                    select
                    onChange={(e) => { setFormDAta({ ...formData, idResponsable: Number(e.target.value) }) }}
                    value={formData.idResponsable}
                    margin="dense"
                    variant="outlined"
                    style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                    label="Reponsable"
                    fullWidth
                >
                    <MenuItem value="0">Selecciona un responsable</MenuItem>
                    {empleados.map(empleado => (
                        <MenuItem value={empleado.idEmpleado} key={empleado.idEmpleado}>{empleado.nombre}</MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </TextField>
}
```

De este modo solo renderizará eñ select cuando haya acabado de hacer la llamada a la api.

No estoy seguro si el problema es este o es un tema de los async await que alguno no espera bien.